# What am I missing with OAuth token exchange process?

Tags: magento2, oauth

Magento has two important documents that outline how OAuth 1.0a authentication/authorization works ([here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html) and [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/webapi/integration.html)).  There also appears to be a [Magento sponsored example](https://gist.github.com/anupdugar/2870f28a5c108cc43df9) of OAuth.

There are two important steps:

1. Server to server POST for initial OAuth key exchange to the Callback URL.  `oauth_consumer_key`, `oauth_consumer_secret`, `oauth_verifier`, and `store_base_url` are sent.
2. User is redirected with a GET to the Identity Link URL.  `consumer_id` and `success_call_back` are sent.

How in the world are #1 and #2 connected?

I don't see any common data and the example from Magento just uses a common session, which I can only assume is a horrible idea.  Even more confusing is why `consumer_id` is sent with the user.

Comment: Maybe I should assume that this has never been used or there is no practical way to use it.  I am considering using just the token based authentication instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is resolved in the latest version of https://github.com/magento/magento2 (and will be available in 2.1.0 I suppose).

Now `consumer_id` is replaced with `oauth_consumer_key` in all requests. And thus `oauth_consumer_key` can be used as correlation ID. Here is a [fork](https://gist.github.com/paliarush/4c2bfa81ebef57305ba4) of the original example you mentioned. This fork is compatible with the latest version of Magento 2.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is the [commit](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/dc0d5026e67a845a273cbbe61a3e497e9969b264)

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like **the example is wrong**. Not sure how you found out it was a "Magento sponsored example" by the way.

The *first step you mentionned is right, that is the **activation** step*.

However the **second step is wrong** as there is ***no need to send the `consumer_id`*** (you can clearly see that this variable is not even used in the `checklogin.php` script).

On top of that, the **use of this variable is never mentionned in the official documentation** so I reckon that was mostly for testing purpose.

My advice is to **stick to the official doc, scripts found online can sometimes be misleading.**

Comment: Besides the poor example I found, this does not actually answer the question.  These two requests are sent from separate web clients (first being from the server directly, second from the users' browser) and no "link" can be made between them as nothing common is shared.  The official documents and examples offer no clue (that I have seen).

Comment: I guess this is [why](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/829#issuecomment-70698994) I feel like it is official.